# How can we force getattribute() to be called for magic methods (special methods)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass, new-style-class

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup) states that `__getattribute__` may be bypassed when looking up special methods. This is the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or built-in functions.

For example,

```
elem = container[0]
```

is not the same as:

```
elem = container.__getattribute__('__getitem__')[0]
```

Below is a another example:

```
class WrappedList:
    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'interal_list', ['apple', 'pear', 'orange'])

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        interal_list = object.__getattribute__(self, 'interal_list')
        attr = getattr(interal_list, attr_name)
        return attr

wl = WrappedList()

print("\nSTART TEST 01 ------------------------")
try:
    print(wl[0]) # throws TypeError: 'WrappedList' object does not support indexing
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)

print("\nSTART TEST 02 ------------------------")
try:
    getitem = getattr(wl, '__getitem__')
    print(getitem(0)) # works just fine
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
```

I would like to write a class named something like `MagicOverrider` where any class which inherits from `MagicOverrider` **always** calls `__getattribute__`, instead of going around it. My question is how can we do this?

I tried the following:

```
class MagicOverrider:

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__call__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__iter__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__getitem__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__setitem__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __add__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__add__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __sub__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__sub__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mul__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__mul__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __truediv__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__truediv__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __floordiv__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__floordiv__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mod__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__mod__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __divmod__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__divmod__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __pow__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__pow__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __lshift__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__lshift__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rshift__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rshift__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __and__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__and__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __xor__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__xor__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __or__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__or__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __radd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__radd__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rsub__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rsub__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rmul__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rmul__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rtruediv__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rtruediv__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rfloordiv__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rfloordiv__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rmod__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rmod__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rdivmod__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rdivmod__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rpow__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rpow__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rlshift__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rlshift__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rrshift__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rrshift__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rand__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rand__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rxor__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rxor__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __neg__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__neg__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __pos__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__pos__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __abs__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__abs__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __invert__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__invert__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __complex__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__complex__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__int__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __float__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__float__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __round__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__round__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __index__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__index__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__eq__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ne__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__ne__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __lt__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__lt__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __le__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__le__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __gt__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__gt__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ge__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__ge__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __bool__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__bool__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__new__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__del__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __slots__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__slots__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __hash__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__hash__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __instancecheck__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__instancecheck__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __subclasscheck__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__subclasscheck__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __subclasshook__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__subclasshook__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ror__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__ror__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iadd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__iadd__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __isub__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__isub__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __imul__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__imul__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __itruediv__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__itruediv__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ifloordiv__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__ifloordiv__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __imod__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__imod__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ipow__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__ipow__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ilshift__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__ilshift__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __irshift__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__irshift__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iand__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__iand__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ixor__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__ixor__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__repr__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__str__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __cmp__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__cmp__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __rcmp__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__rcmp__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __nonzero__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__nonzero__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = getattr(self, '__unicode__')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, my solution has at least two problems:

- It won't work anymore if new magic methods are introduced in a future release of python
- the first line, `class MagicOverrider:`, throws `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 8):

This is tricky. 
Because when triggering the magic methods via language constructs, Python does not go through the normal attribute-retrieval path that is used in normal cases (that is, with `__getattribute__` and so on): instead, whenever a special method is assigned to a class, it is marked in the binary data structure of the class itself (that is done by the C code in the Python interpreter). It is done so that this usage is shortcut -otherwise it would be too much code just to get the correct method to perform, say an addition, or an item retrieval. And there also, would be easy to have some infinite recurse loops.

So - the magic method is always retrieved directly bt Python - no `__getattribute__`.

What is possible to do instead is to have the magicmethods themselves to trigger the `__getattribute__` as they are running. If they get any result different from themselves, they call that instead. Just take some care to avoid infinite recursion.

As for the potential magic methods: since this requires a metaclass anyway, it is just a matter of having the metaclass to wrap all magic methods for the desired class when creating the class that will force `__getattribute__` .

The code bellow does that, and includes an example class that puts an ad-hoc wrapper on `__getitem__`:

```
from functools import wraps
from threading import local as thread_local
from types import MethodType

def wrap(name, method):
    local_flag = thread_local()
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        local_method = method
        if not getattr(local_flag, "running", False) and args and not isinstance(args[0], type):
            local_flag.running = True
            # trigger __getattribute__:
            self = args[0]
            cls = self.__class__
            retrieved = cls.__getattribute__(self, name)
            if not retrieved is wrapper:
                local_method =  retrieved
            if isinstance(local_method, MethodType):
                args = args[1:]
        result = local_method(*args, **kw)
        local_flag.running = False
        return result
    wrapper._wrapped = True
    return wrapper


class MetaOverrider(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwd):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace, **kwd)

        for name in dir(cls):
            if not (name.startswith("__")  and name.endswith("__")):
                continue
            if name in ("__getattribute__", "__class__", "__init__"):
                continue
            magic_method = getattr(cls, name)
            if not callable(magic_method) or getattr(magic_method, "_wrapped", False):
                continue
            setattr(cls, name, wrap(name, magic_method))



class TestOverriding(list, metaclass=MetaOverrider):
    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(attrname)
        if attrname == "__getitem__":
            original = attr
            def printergetitem(self, index):
                print("Getting ", index)
                return original(index)
            attr = printergetitem
        return attr
```

It will work with any magic method - but of course, if you just assign the magic-method to the class itself after it is created, it will shadow the wrapper method used. But for any magic wrapping added in `__getattribute__` itself it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hook or option you can set to turn on regular attribute handling for all magic methods. The only way you could do that is by overriding all of them to delegate to your desired handling individually, which has a few important limitations, one of which you caught:

- It needs to be updated every time a magic method is introduced.
- It's easy to miss a method.
- Whatever attribute lookup process you delegate to will probably pick up your delegator method. That needs careful handling.

Your attempt failed because you tried to define `__slots__` as an instance method. `__slots__` is not supposed to be any sort of method at all, and definitely not an instance method; it needs to be a sequence, and it needs to be processed at class definition time to decide the layout of instances of your class. You also tried to write `__new__` as if it was an instance method. Even if you hadn't made those mistakes, though, most of your methods would just end up in infinite recursive loops.