# Is there a standard class that implements all the int-like magic methods by calling int(self)?

Tags: python

Please note: I have made edits since some of these responses were given, due to my bad wording. Blame me. Thanks to everyone for putting up with me.

I am writing a class that has int-like properties.

It implements the `__int__` method.

I'd like to implement all the magic methods that ints have: `__add__`, `__and__`, `__rshift__` etc., by applying the same function on `int(self)`.

For example:

```
  def __lshift__(self, other):
    return int(self) << other

  def __bool__(self):
    return bool(int(self))

  # and so forth, for about 40 more methods.
```

Is there an object that will do this for me? It seems like this would be a common pattern.

I tried with `class MyClass(int)`, but this did not allow me to override `__int__`

My class is *not* an int; I want it to be able to be treated as an int.

Or should I be doing this some other way?

I am trying to simulate FPGA wires & registers - the value will change dynamically.

For example, if inst.wire2 is defined as `inst.wire1 + 10`, then `inst.wire2` will always be `inst.wire1 + 10`; if inst.wire1 changes, inst.wire2 changes with it.

Once complete, almost all access to a given wire or register will be for it's value, so making every reference `inst.wire1.value` (or `self.wire1.value`) will clutter the code immensely, with no advantage.

TO CLARIFY: if someone treats the property as an int (e.g. by adding a number to it), the result should be a regular, real, actual int, with no magic stuff.

Comment: As a very general rule, this is almost always a bad idea.  If it looks like an `int`, then people expect it to be an `int`, and not something that mostly smells like an `int`.  Can't you do what you need through encapsulation, by having your class CONTAIN an `int`?

Comment: do you want to do something like this? https://ideone.com/TTERxO

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of why you might want to do this?

Comment: You can almost do it with `__getattr__`, but magic methods require special consideration -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966182/how-can-we-force-getattribute-to-be-called-for-magic-methods-special-methods

Comment: @AugustoVasques the value can change at any time, so it has to be calculated on demand.

Comment: @TimRoberts Are you saying Duck Typing is bad? https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing

Comment: I said nothing of the kind.  I'm talking about maintainability -- the principle of least astonishment.  You are violating one of the fundamental principles of `int`s -- that they are  immutable.  No programmer is going to expect that.  If you have a complete domain-specific language, that's OK, but it's going to cause problems in the future.

Comment: Plus, in order for this to work, you can't hope to write `wire1 = wire1 + 3`.  That's doesn't modify the existing `wire1`.  It creates a NEW `wire1`, which will terminate the connection to `wire2` To have it be immutable, you absolutely need the `wire1.value` construct.  Python is not Verilog.

Comment: @TimRoberts `wire1 = wire1 + 3` makes no sense on an FPGA.  Also, is what I'm describing not ducktyping, or did you not say, about what I was describing "As a very general rule, this is almost always a bad idea." ? Properties aren't immutable, but they might well be indistinguishable from an int (in the sense that they return an int).

Comment: Any statement like `wire1 = xxxx` will break the connection.

Comment: This is the reason I don't like mentioning what I'm going to use this for :( . We've ended up down a massive rabbit-hole, of things that have nothing to do with my question. I have an object with a property. I've implemented an __int__ for it. Is there an easier way to make all the functions that work on an `int` work on my property, returning a regular int, without implementing each function, one-by-one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out an answer (not necessarily the best one, but it works).

There are two parts to this.

One part is how to calculate the values on demand. This is done using the `__get__` method.

The other part is to create a class which inherits from `__int__` (thanks @Augusto Vasques for pointing me at that!).

In part, my code reads something like:

```
import time

class LikeInt(int):
    # if you want to add arguments to __init__,
    # these same arguments are passed to __new__
    # so you have to ignore them in __new__
    # not needed here, as I'm not adding any arguments,
    # but it would look like this.
    #def __new__(cls, x, *args, **kwargs):
    #  return int.__new__(cls, x)

    def something(self):
        print("something!")

class Wire(object):
  def __init__(self, function):
    self.__function__ = function

  def __get__(self, pinstance = None, pclass = None):
    if pinstance == None:
      raise AttributeError()

    value = self.__function__(pinstance)
    print("turns out ", self.__function__.__name__, " is ", value, "right now")

    return LikeInt(value)

def AutoDecorator(Class, **kwargs):
  def AutoDecorate(function):
    return Class(function = function, **kwargs)
  return AutoDecorate

class MyCircuit(object):
  @AutoDecorator(Class = Wire)
  def myfirstwire(self):
    return int(time.time()) # this is just an example of a changing value

  @AutoDecorator(Class = Wire)
  def mysecondwire(self):
    return self.myfirstwire + 1

inst = MyCircuit()

# this will trigger inst.myfirstwire._get_, which creates a LikeInt.
inst.myfirstwire.something()

# this will trigger inst.mysecondwire._get_; this will run the function, which then triggers inst.myfirstwire.__get__
print(inst.mysecondwire + 2)

time.sleep(5)
print(inst.mysecondwire + 2)
```

This is, of course, a massive simplification; it doesn't include register etc., but it meets the criteria of the question:

- inst.myfirstwire and inst.mysecondwire implement add/and/rshift etc., without me having to code them one-by-one
- mysecondwire will always be one more than myfirstwire (at any given instant)
- you can `print(inst.mysecondwire + 10)`
- when you treat inst.mysecondwire as an int (e.g. by adding a number to it) the result is a regular, real, actual int, with no magic stuff.

In case someone else uses this,

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would use would be to split your wire class into several related classes: an abstract superclass that implements all the operators, a class that represents an input wire, and two classes that represent binary and unary operators.

Here's a start:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from collections.abc import Callable
import operator

class Wire(ABC):
    def __add__(self, other: 'Wire | int') -> 'Wire':
        return BinopWire(self, other, operator.add)

    def __radd__(self, other: 'Wire | int') -> 'Wire':
        return BinopWire(other, self, operator.add)

    # ...

    def __lshift__(self, other: 'Wire | int') -> 'Wire':
        return BinopWire(self, other, operator.lshift)

    def __rlshift__(self, other: 'Wire | int') -> 'Wire':
        return BinopWire(other, self, operator.lshift)

    def __neg__(self) -> 'Wire':
        return UnopWire(self, operator.neg)

    def __inv__(self) -> 'Wire':
        return UnopWire(self, operator.inv)

    @abstractmethod
    def __int__(self) -> int:
        ...

    def __bool__(self) -> bool:
        return bool(int(self))

@dataclass
class InputWire(Wire):
    value: int

    def __int__(self) -> int:
        return self.value

@dataclass
class BinopWire(Wire):
    left: Wire | int
    right: Wire | int
    op: Callable[[int, int], int]

    def __int__(self) -> int:
        return self.op(int(self.left), int(self.right))

@dataclass
class UnopWire(Wire):
    arg: Wire | int
    op: Callable[[int], int]

    def __int__(self) -> int:
        return self.op(int(self.arg))


wire1 = InputWire(7)
wire2 = wire1 + 7
print(int(wire2))
wire3 = -wire2
wire1.value = 3
print(int(wire3))
```

This approach allows you to construct wires that can be evaluated multiple times, with different inputs.

Comment: This is essentially implementing deferred evaluation, right?  Interesting approach.  It still results in surprising behavior to the uninitiated.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this does not answer my question at all: "Is there a standard class that implements all the int-like magic methods by calling int(self)?"

Comment: The answer to that question would be "no, and that wouldn't do what you want it to if it existed".